Como unificar en una sola fila la suma total de una categoria si esta tiene varios valores
Tengo el siguiente Código
    SELECT
    music_store.Customer.Country,
    music_store.Genre.Name AS Genero,
    music_store.Invoice.Total,
    SUM(music_store.Invoice.Total)    
    FROM music_store.Genre
    INNER JOIN music_store.Track ON music_store.Genre.GenreId = music_store.Track.GenreId
    INNER JOIN music_store.InvoiceLine ON music_store.Track.TrackId = music_store.InvoiceLine.TrackId
    INNER JOIN music_store.Invoice ON music_store.InvoiceLine.InvoiceId = music_store.Invoice.InvoiceId
    INNER JOIN music_store.Customer ON music_store.Invoice.CustomerId = music_store.Customer.CustomerId

WHERE  music_store.Customer.Country ='United Kingdom' AND music_store.Genre.Name ='Rock'

GROUP BY music_store.Customer.Country, music_store.Genre.Name,music_store.Invoice.Total 

Y me da como resultado lo siguiente:
Country    Genero   Total   TOTAL
United Kingdom  Rock    9.90    336.60
United Kingdom  Rock    7.92    102.96
United Kingdom  Rock    8.91    258.39
United Kingdom  Rock    12.87   334.62
United Kingdom  Rock    1.98    3.96
United Kingdom  Rock    6.93    55.44
United Kingdom  Rock    5.94    17.82
United Kingdom  Rock    4.95    44.55
United Kingdom  Rock    3.96    11.88
United Kingdom  Rock    10.89   119.79
United Kingdom  Rock    15.84   253.44
United Kingdom  Rock    11.88   142.56

Quiero que solo me de una fila con el total de ese categoría. Ya probé usando un SUM dentro del primer SUM pero me da error. De antemano muchas gracias.

Y porque necesitas mostrar la columna total???

pon el ejemplo del resultado que esperas.

¿Probaste quitando music_store.Invoice.Total del GROUP BY?

Con
GROUP BY customer.country, genre.name, invoice.total 

recibes un resultado con una fila por customer.country, genre.name y invoice.total. Si tus tablas contienen



customer.country
genre.name
invoice.total




United Kingdom
Rock
10


United Kingdom
Rock
10


United Kingdom
Rock
50



El resultado será



customer.country
genre.name
invoice.total
SUM(invoice.total)




United Kingdom
Rock
10
20


United Kingdom
Rock
50
50



(En tus tablas tienes 34 veces el total de 9.90 para United Kingdom y Rock. Entonces ves 9.90 con 336.60.)
Lo que quieres en vez es una fila por customer.country y genre.name con
GROUP BY customer.country, genre.name

Consulta con aliases para la legibilidad:
SELECT
  c.country,
  g.name as genero,
  SUM(i.total) AS factura_total
FROM music_store.track t
JOIN music_store.invoiceline il ON il.trackid   = t.trackid
JOIN music_store.invoice i      ON i.invoiceid  = il.invoiceid
JOIN music_store.customer c     ON c.customerid = i.customerid
JOIN music_store.genre g        ON g.genreid    = t.genreid
WHERE c.country = 'United Kingdom'
AND g.name = 'Rock'
GROUP BY c.country, g.name
ORDER BY c.country, g.name;

o
SELECT
  c.country,
  g.name as genero,
  SUM(i.total) AS factura_total
FROM music_store.track t
JOIN music_store.invoiceline il ON il.trackid   = t.trackid
JOIN music_store.invoice i ON i.invoiceid  = il.invoiceid
WHERE t.genreid = (SELECT g.genreid FROM music_store.genre g WHERE g.name = 'Rock')
AND i.customerid IN (SELECT c.customerid FROM music_store.customer c WHERE c.country = 'United Kingdom')
GROUP BY c.country, g.name
ORDER BY c.country, g.name;

